# @PostConstruct Interceptor with @Named @ViewScoped not invoked

Tags: java, jsf-2, cdi, interceptor, seam3

I have read carefully the article about [Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/interceptors.html) in the Seam/Weld documentation and implemented a `InterceptorBinding`:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface MyLog {}
```

and a `Interceptor` class:

```
@MyLog @Interceptor
public class ErpLogInterceptor implements Serializable
{
  @AroundInvoke
  public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception
  {..}

  @PostConstruct
  public Object logPostConstruct(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception
  {...}
}
```

No I tried to activated the interceptor in the `@Named @ViewScoped` bean:

```
@javax.inject.Named;
@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable
{
  @PostConstruct @MyLog
  public void init()
  {...}

  @MyLog public void toggleButton()
  {..}
}
```

If I push a button on my JSF page the method `toggleButton` is invoked correctly **and** the Interceptor method `logMethodEntry` is called. But it seems the method `@PostConstruct` (I am interested in) is never intercepted by my class.

The question seems to be related to [Java EE Interceptors and @ViewScoped bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841351) but actually my interceptor is working in *normal* methods.

Comment: Are you using CODI as outlined in the answer of the linked question? The JSF-specific `@ViewScoped` otherwise simply don't work in CDI-specific `@Named`.

Comment: Are you sure the interceptors work for lifecycle methods?

Comment: @AdrianMitev: At least these interceptors are described in the document I'm referencing.

Comment: What happens if you use a CDI scope instead of the JSF one (yes I know Seam 3 changes it, but there may be something with the interceptors it isn't doing)?

Comment: @LightGuard: Changed the scope to `@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`, but nothing during `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a bug, however, we're no longer doing work on Seam 3.

Comment: @LightGuard: I know you're heavily involved in Seam3, and this question is most probably off-topic, but what exactly do you mean with "we're no longer doing work on Seam 3"? Can you point to a URL?

Comment: The last release was 3.1.0.Final nearly a year ago. We're putting our efforts into Apache DeltaSpike.

Answer (score 1):

You should set return type of `@PostConstruct` interceptor to `void` not `Object`.
Change:

```
  @PostConstruct
  public Object logPostConstruct(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception
  {...}
```

to:

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void logPostConstruct(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception
  {...}
```